# .Net Build and File Save in App_Code folder

Tags: visual-studio-2008, app-code

In Visual Studio 2008, when I save a file in the App_Code folder it takes quite a lot longer to save than a similar sized file that is located outside of App_Code folder.

Similarly, when I make changes to the code in a file in the App_Code folder, it takes the .Net Solution a lot longer to compile than it does when making code changes in other files.  What is the reason for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar report on the connect.microsoft.com site. The microsoft solution pointed to a plugin Document!X, but that didn't seem to cover all reported cases. There are a couple of comments which states that the problem occurs without the plugin (like this post).

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/368690/visual-studio-2008-sp1-ide-temporarily-freezes-when-saving-code-files

Other people in my office have also confirmed that this problem is happening for them. Maybe it's a common plugin we all use. But, I'm hoping there is a setting we can change to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I have never noticed a difference, but if want to eliminate the app_code folder completely you can switch to a web application as opposed to a web site project and then you will be able to move these files into a separate project if you would like.

Enjoy!